# export and import of products problems in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, importexport

I exported products from Magento 2.0.5 and want to import to Magento 2.1.1

I got the following error:

> Data validation failed. Please fix the following errors and upload the
>   file again. Following Error(s) has been occurred during importing
>   process: Only the first 100 errors are shown. Download full report
>   1. Product Type is invalid or not supported in row(s): 52, 53, 73, 74, 75, 528, 529 Checked rows: 529, checked entities: 529, invalid rows:
>   7, total errors: 7

Comment: Check your csv file for the product type column

Comment: now it is working fine all products is imported  Sir but products images not showing ?can you help me ? i exported the products from abc.com and  imported now to xyz.com now all products are coming to xyz.com but no images on it ??

Comment: Did you added the images of abc.com to your xyz.com before importing the products?  This link might help you https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-import-all-products-with-images-magento-2.html

Comment: there are images in abc.com all images for all products are added there